# In Wordpress, how to order by custom field when there is more than one custom field in the query?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am editing an existing Wordpress theme that uses custom fields in a custom query. I need to edit the query so that the results are filtered by one custom field, and ordered by a second custom field.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
<?php
$query_args = array();
$query_args['post_type'] = 'woo_estate';
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'on_show',
        'value' => 'true'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'type' => 'numeric',
    )
);
$query_args['orderby'] = 'price';
$query_args['order'] = 'ASC';

$query_args['posts_per_page'] = $woo_options['woo_more_entries'];
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query_args['paged'] = $paged;

?>
    <?php query_posts(  $query_args ); ?>
```

The problem is that the results continue to be ordered by the default (date) instead of by the `price` custom field.

How do I get this query to order by the custom price field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a bit in the documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query I was able to come up with code that accomplished what I needed.

```
$query_args = array();
$query_args['post_type'] = 'woo_estate';
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'on_show',
        'value' => 'true'
    )
);

$query_args['meta_key'] = 'price';
$query_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$query_args['order'] = 'DESC';

$query_args['posts_per_page'] = $woo_options['woo_more_entries'];
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query_args['paged'] = $paged;

query_posts(    $query_args )
```

Comment: +1, for this nice answer on your own question that you have figured out by yourself by digging the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

To order by a custom field you have to add `meta_key` in your array and `orderby` should be `meta_value` or `meta_value_num` for numbers, so in this case it should be `meta_value_num` because it's a numeric.

```
$query_args['meta_key'] = 'price';
$query_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$query_args['order'] = 'ASC';
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'on_show',
        'value' => 'true'
    )
);
// ...
```

[Here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610836/list-custom-post-type-by-custom-field-date/13611296#13611296), you may take a look at this too.